# Can I do profiller with Glimpse on clear web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, glimpse

I have two separate project webapi and client side on angular.

So I installed Glipse ef6\mvc, but it work only on client project, but I need it on webapi project, but on webapi I cann't have access to */Glimpse.xsd.

So how enable *.xsd ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Glimpse to WebAPI project and launch the Glimpse Tool as Standalone Tool to debug the WebAPI requests.